# How to use GroupBy and Sum in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

I'm struggling with GroupBy and Sum in the following query using SelectMany. Could someone show me how to sum two fields as well as how to group by and order by several fields.

```
var Rows = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
{
  OA = t[4],
  CD = t[5],
  PD = t[0],
  DS = Convert.ToInt32(t[9]),
  CS = Convert.ToInt32(t[10])
}))
// Pseudo-code:
//.GroupBy(CD)
//.GroupBy(OA)
//.GroupBy(PD)
//.Sum(u=> u.DS)
//.Sum(u => u.CS)
.OrderBy(u => u.CD)
.ThenBy(u => u.OA)
.ThenBy(u => u.PD)
.ToList();
```

Object:

```
List<DataProperty> allData = new List<DataProperty>();
```

DataProperty consists of

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _headers = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
private readonly List<string[]> _rows = new List<string[]>();
```

The original query before the C# rewrite from ColdFusion:

> ```
> SELECT 
> OA,
> CD,
> PD,               
> sum(DS) as DS
> sum(CS) as CS
> FROM qDistinct
> GROUP BY 
> CD,
> OA,
> PD
> ORDER BY 
> ucaseCD,
> OA,
> PD
> ```

If the GroupBy is coded differently in the following query without Sum, could you also please show me how to do it?

```
var Rows = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
{
  OA = t[4],
  PD = t[0]      
}))
// Pseudo-code:
//.GroupBy(OA)
//.GroupBy(PD)   
.OrderBy(u => u.OA)
.ThenBy(u => u.PD)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want - something like this?

```
var Rows = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
{
  OA = t[4],
  CD = t[5],
  PD = t[0],
  DS = Convert.ToInt32(t[9]),
  CS = Convert.ToInt32(t[10])
}))
// group by the combination of CD, OA, and PD
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CD, x,OA, x.PD } )
// sum DS and CS within each group
.Select (g => new {g.Key.CD, 
                   g.Key.OA, 
                   g.Key.PD,  
                   DS = g.Sum(u=> u.DS), 
                   CS = g.Sum(u=> u.CS) 
                  } ) 
.OrderBy(u => u.CD)
.ThenBy(u => u.OA)
.ThenBy(u => u.PD)
```

Comment: This was the query before the C# rewrite from ColdFusion:

Comment: Please add it to your question so if can be formatted properly.